# cut the right side of a '=' delimited string and storing into a list in python

Tags: python, string

A beginner question
My file looks like -->

```
10.5.5.81=apache,php,solr 
10.5.5.100=oracle,coherence
```

How can I cut the IP part and store it into a list for further processing?
Please help.

Comment: Have a look at the `str.split` function https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.split :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
answer = []
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        answer.append(line.partition('=')[0].strip())
```

Comment: And `str.partition()` is faster than a limited `str.split()`...